# Can Cocos2D handle these graphic requirements?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm wanting to build a game with some simple effects.

1. I want to add the warping effect that you see in games like geometry wars and geodefence. I know how to implement this effect in OpenGL ES. Would I be able to add this to a Cocos2D created app?
2. I want to have a 3D model that only moves on a 2D plane. It may rotate. First, can I add OpenGL shading to the model? Second, can I have Box2D physics applied to it like it was a 2D sprite?

That's about it. Those are the main functionality I'm hoping I can add to a Cocos2D application and am trying to figure out if I can before I spend a lot of time learning how to use the game engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes, you can intermix Cocos2D and OpenGL ES together - you can override the CCNode's "draw" method and do just about anything you'd like in there (such as rotating, scaling, etc in OpenGL with the texture).

2) You can add the model, and you can shade the model - yes.  If you create the body fixtures for the model from Box2D, but treat the Model as if it were a '2d sprite' (has set width/height) - yes, you can use Box2D - but understand that it will only react within the 2D Physics World, and won't have any depth applied to it.

It should be noted though, that though these are possible, you will still need to implement the code to do so on your own.

Comment: Cool. That's what I was wanting to know.